# problem with start VM

Tags: samba, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I used one computer to build a VM which include images and XML(compute node). I installed samba server in another to share directory which will content images of all my VMs (storage node). Then I copied images of VMs to the shared directory which is mounted from storage node, configured the link inside XML and tried to start VM by virsh command. It didn't work and I don't know how to solve it.

Is it possible to run a VM in one machine with the images of it is stored in a shared directory of another?

Thank for your help!

Comment: It is definitely possible to run a vm from shared storage, I do all the time from smb shares (virtualbox and VMware) and from nfs shares (proxmox). I'm not too familiar with virsh but what was the error or output you received after the command?

Comment: The error output is : unable to set user and group to 64055:131 on /...test.img. I tried to add user to samba, change all shared files to 777 but it didn't work/

Comment: Is the user in the qemu/libvirt group? Or did you configure the groups when making the machine? [This](https://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html) says the default user and group is root:root, and might give some additional info. If someone can elaborate please do.

Comment: Thank, I add the user to the libvirt and change owner and the group of the directory then it showed another error: 
ibvirtError: internal error: cannot load AppArmor profile 'libvirt-cc77dd32-d66a-4913-ab73-f7c56ca8a7a8'
Do you have any idea?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on? I found this post from 2012 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069297/create-virtual-machine-using-libvirt-error-related-to-apparmor that says here's a bug in libvirt(I would imagine it would be fixed by now)